# How to get cycling duration from HealthKit for ios app using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, healthkit, hksamplequery

I am creating an app where I am reading data from health-Kit. I am able to read number of steps, Running + Walking etc. now i am trying to read the date and duration of cycling. This is what I was using for Running + Walking

```
func readDistanceWalkingRunning(completion: (([AnyObject]!, NSError!) -> Void)!) {
    let runningWalking = HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning)
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(-86400.0), endDate: NSDate(), options: HKQueryOptions.None)

    let stepsSampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: runningWalking!,
                                         predicate: predicate,
                                         limit: 100,
                                         sortDescriptors: nil)
    { [weak self] (query, results, error) in

        if let results = results as? [HKQuantitySample] {

            for result in results {
                print(" Distance was " + " \(result.quantity.doubleValueForUnit(HKUnit.mileUnit())) ")
                print("Date was " + "\(result.startDate)")

            }
        }
    }

    // Don't forget to execute the Query!
    executeQuery(stepsSampleQuery)
}
```

And everything is fine, But when I try to read distance for cycling using the code below, I am getting nil result. Cycling data is showing in appleHealth app but Why am I getting result as nil ? Please help

```
    func readDistanceCycling(completion: (([AnyObject]!, NSError!) -> Void)!) {
    let distanceCycling = HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceCycling)
    let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(NSDate(), endDate: NSDate(), options: HKQueryOptions.None)

    let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: distanceCycling!, predicate: predicate, limit: 100, sortDescriptors: nil, resultsHandler: { query, result, error in


if result != nil
{
    print("We have some Data")
}
else
{
    print("Result is nil")
}

if let results = result as? [HKQuantitySample] {

    for result in results {
        print(" Quantity type " + " \(result.quantityType) ")
        print("Date was " + "\(result.startDate)")

    }
}
})

    executeQuery(query)
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use given below function. It give you leatest 7 record. According to your requirement you can also change it.

```
func getHealthDataValue ( HealthQuantityType : HKQuantityType , strUnitType : String , GetBackFinalhealthData: ((( healthValues : [AnyObject] ) -> Void)!) )
{          
    if let heartRateType = HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HealthQuantityType.identifier)
    {
        if (HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable()  ){

            let sortByTime = NSSortDescriptor(key:HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending:false)

            //            let timeFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            //            timeFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
            //yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZ

            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"

        let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType:heartRateType, predicate:nil, limit:7, sortDescriptors:[sortByTime], resultsHandler:{(query, results, error) in

            guard let results = results else {

                //include the healthkit error in log
                if let errorDescription = error!.description as String?
                {

                    GetBackFinalhealthData (healthValues: ["nodata"])
                }
                return
            }

            var arrHealthValues     = [AnyObject]()

            for quantitySample in results {
                let quantity = (quantitySample as! HKQuantitySample).quantity
                let healthDataUnit : HKUnit
                if (strUnitType.length > 0 ){
                    healthDataUnit = HKUnit(fromString: strUnitType)
                }else{
                    healthDataUnit = HKUnit.countUnit()
                }

                let tempActualhealthData = "\(quantity.doubleValueForUnit(healthDataUnit))"
                let tempActualRecordedDate = "\(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(quantitySample.startDate))"
                if  (tempActualhealthData.length > 0){
                    let dicHealth : [String:AnyObject] = [HealthValue.kIdentifierValue :tempActualhealthData , HealthValue.kRecordDate :tempActualRecordedDate , HealthValue.kIdentifierDisplayUnit : strUnitType ]

                    arrHealthValues.append(dicHealth)
                }
            }

            if  (arrHealthValues.count > 0)
            {
                GetBackFinalhealthData (healthValues: arrHealthValues)
            }
            else
            {
                GetBackFinalhealthData (healthValues: [HealthValue.kNoData])
            }
        })
        (self.HealthStore as! HKHealthStore).executeQuery(query)
    }
}
```

}

Use above function as follow.
Here you need to pass a type and unit.

```
self.getHealthDataValue(HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBloodPressureDiastolic), strUnitType: "mmHg"
                ) { (arrHealth) -> Void in                  
            }
```

Comment: will it give me cycling records ? :-o

Comment: This method give everything you want.

Comment: But you need to call method properly

Comment: I am a begginer can you guide me please How can I fetch cycling records using your method ?

Comment: and where is ** GetBackFinalhealthData** declared ?

Comment: No need to declare it is a Completionblock block

Comment: i m getting use of unresolved identified "heartRateType"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117052/discussion-between-hitesh-surani-and-byte).

Comment: Thanks you soo much its Working now

Comment: Your well come dear. You can also edit my answer if need a any modification.

Comment: can i get walking time and Running time using this functions

Comment: Yes, You can any attribute from healthkit.